# Send Request to a Web Service with PHP and cURL

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I'm learning how to send a request to a web service using PHP and cURL. I found this link and was able to get the 'zip code' example to work.

[Consume WebService with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379339/consume-webservice-with-php)

WebserviceX.NET also has 'stock quote' web service.

http://www.webservicex.net/ws/WSDetails.aspx?CATID=2&WSID=9

I'm using the same method used for the 'zip code' example but I can't get this one to work. Here is the code.

```
$url = "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx/GetQuote?symbol=AAPL";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$xmlobj = simplexml_load_string($result);
```

The code runs successfully but I can't access the XML object. I thought this would work.

```
echo $xmlobj->StockQuotes->Stock->Symbol;
```

The issue seems to be that $result is not in the right format or it's not loading into the XML object correctly. I have tried many approaches using DOMDocument and SimpleXMLElement but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: What's the `var_dump($result);` output?

Comment: @JohnConde: Here is the error message - Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @Sammaye: Here is the var_dump - object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(423) "<StockQuotes><Stock><Symbol>AAPL</Symbol><Last>566.97</Last><Date>6/28/2012</Date><Time>3:24pm</Time><Change>-7.53</Change><Open>571.85</Open><High>574.00</High><Low>565.61</Low><Volume>7812572</Volume><MktCap>530.2B</MktCap><PreviousClose>574.50</PreviousClose><PercentageChange>-1.31%</PercentageChange><AnnRange>331.88 - 644.00</AnnRange><Earns>41.042</Earns><P-E>14.00</P-E><Name>Apple Inc.</Name></Stock></StockQuotes>"
}

Comment: Yea you see $result has already been parsed as the simpleXMLELement try just using the object notation directly on $result.

Comment: @Sammaye: oops, that was var_dump($xmlobj)... I have tried object notation on that to no avail... here is var_dump($result) -- string(732) "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">&lt;StockQuotes&gt;&lt;Stock&gt;&lt;Symbol&gt;AAPL&lt;/Symbol&gt;&lt;Last&gt;569.05&lt;/Last&gt;&lt;Date&gt;6/28/2012&lt;/Date&gt;&lt;Time&gt;4:00pm&lt;/Time&gt;&lt;Change&gt;-5.45&lt;/Change&gt;&lt;Open&gt;571.85&lt;/Open&gt;&lt;High&gt;574.00&lt;/High&gt;&lt;Low&gt;565.61&lt;/Low&gt;&lt;Volume&gt;9891718&lt;/Volume&gt;&lt;MktCap&gt;532.1B&lt;/MktCap&gt;&lt;...